# can i downgrade app from production to beta testing in Playstore

Tags: android, google-play

Hi accidently uploaded an apk to production , instead of beta. Is it possible to dowgrade it to beta , without having an apk in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly remove the app from the play store and use the beta/alpha testing tabs on the developer console. I am not sure about how beta works, but if you choose alpha testing,your app doesn't go into production. You are send a link for your app and you need to send invites to people on their google+ accounts so that they can access your app and be able to download it.

UPDATE:
Right from the official docs

```
Alpha- or beta-test apps will only appear in Google Play for testers that opt-in and not to any other users.
A production APK is not required to publish an alpha- or beta-test app.
It may take up to 24 hours after publishing for the test link to become active.
```